# Cron error: sales_send_order_emails has an error: No such entity

Tags: error, cron, magento2.3.3, order-confirmation-email

I have these errors in cron.log:

```
main.ERROR: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails has an error: No such entity with cartId = 0.
```

We also have a problem with email confirmations and they are not being sent. We use 3rd party SMTP extension.

What is that error about and is there a fix to remove that? Might this error have something to do with emails not being sent?

Comment: This is not SMTP problem. Not sure why they load quote in sales email? Check if quote is deleted or something.

Comment: @SohelRana From where do I check that?